# What is the meaning of “poste” in this telephone call context?

Tags: usage

Suppose I call someone (official) and his secretary says

> Le poste est occupé.

What does she mean? Is the person occupied with someone in his office or is he occupied with another telephone call?

Is there another way she could say the same thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Poste* est un nom masculin qui fait référence au téléphone ici. La personne est donc déjà en conversation téléphonique avec quelqu'un d'autre.

La secrétaire aurait aussi pu dire :

> Le téléphone sonne occupé.
>   La ligne est occupée.